# Getting 403 on (presumably) public google storage bucket for MacOS10.13sdk for android emulator development

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, gsutil

I'm trying to [Google's open source Android emulator](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/aca144a9e9264b11c2d729096af90d695d01455d/README.md) for Mac. They're very picky about which versions of things (e.g., Xcode, python) are installed. One specific requirement is `MacOS10.13sdk`, which the [Mac instructions](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/qemu/+/aca144a9e9264b11c2d729096af90d695d01455d/android/docs/DARWIN-DEV.md) say should be retrieved with

```
gsutil cp gs://emu-dev-development/MacOSX10.13.sdk.tar.gz .
```

but that returns

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 <myaccount> does not have storage.objects.list access to the Google Cloud Storage bucket.
```

I'm more of an AWS user, and although I've used Google Cloud from the console for some limited things, this is my first time using the CLI, so I'm sure I'm missing something basic.

I installed `gsutil` per [the instructions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install). I installed their recommended Python3.7:

```
% which python3
/usr/local/opt/python@3.7/bin/python3
```

I've run `gcloud init` twice. Once I selected an existing project from the list, and once I selected "Create a new project". Authentication has clearly worked, because said new project is now visible from the web console.

What am I missing to download from what I'm guessing must be a public bucket?

Comment: Your `gsutil cp` should have a source and a destination. Looks like you're giving only one value. Try adding a space followed by a period to get it to copy the file to your current folder.

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error — edited.

Comment: I tried to access the Bucket today and am unsuccessful. It appears to be (no longer) available at that location.